# Elements are not displayed inside a baloon in Yandex Maps after I click on the Placemark

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, yandex-maps

In Next.js I wrote a functionality that opens the balloon when you click on a marker on the yandex map using the React-yandex-maps library. The problem is that at the first click, the balloon opens and all the elements in it are displayed. Then I click on the cross at the top right of the balloon and on the next clicks the balloon opens, but the elements inside are not displayed:

[image]

Here is the code that I use to display the balloon, it is taken from here: [Article](https://habr.com/ru/articles/677330/)

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

export default function Portal({ children, getHTMLElementId }) {
  // находим искомый HTML по id
  const mount = document.getElementById(getHTMLElementId);
  // создаём свой div
  const el = document.createElement("div");

  useEffect(() => {
    // добавляем свой див к искомому элементу
    if (mount) {
      mount.appendChild(el);
    }
    return () => {
      // удаляем элемент от искомого при завершении компоненты
      if (mount) mount.removeChild(el);
    };
  }, [el, mount]);
  // отменяем отрисовку при отсутствии искомого элемента
  if (!mount) return null;
  // собственно, пририсовываем React-элемент в div к искомому HTML
  return createPortal(children, el);
}
```

Code for displaying everything on the map:

```
const DynamicPortalWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import("./Portal"), {
 ssr: false,
});

function WhMap({ posts, regionPosition, noRegionFlag }) {
 const [activePortal, setActivePortal] = useState(false);
 const [postPopup, setPostPopup] = useState(null);

 const map = useRef();

 return (
   <div>
     <YMaps>
       <Map
         id="map"
         width="100%"
         height="88vh"
         defaultState={{ center: [59.9386, 30.3141], zoom: 13 }}
         // включаем модули, отвечающие за всплывающие окна над геообъектами
         modules={["geoObject.addon.balloon", "geoObject.addon.hint"]}
         instanceRef={map}
       >
         {posts?.map((post) => (
           <>
               <Placemark
                 geometry={[
                   Number(post.latitude),
                   Number(post.longitude),
                 ]}
                 options={{
                   preset: "islands#darkBlueCircleDotIcon",
                   iconColor: "#284AC2",
                 }}
                 properties={{
                   iconContent: "2", // пару символов помещается
                   // создаём пустой элемент с заданными размерами
                   balloonContent:
                     '<div id="driver-2" class="driver-card"></div>',
                 }}
                 onClick={() => {
                   requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                     setActivePortal(true);
                     setPostPopup(post);
                   });
                 }}
               />
           </>
         ))}
       </Map>
       {activePortal && (
         <DynamicPortalWithNoSSR getHTMLElementId="driver-2">
           // здесь контент который отображается внутри balloon
         </DynamicPortalWithNoSSR>
       )}
     </YMaps>
   </Box>
 );
}

export default WhMap;
```

Comment: Try replacing "balloonContent" with "balloonContentBody" - worked for me